# Android textview setTypeFace is not working for hindi text when implementing hindi fonts from Asset

Tags: android, fonts, textview, android-fonts, android-textinputedittext

I take a hindi text value(using gboard hindi keyboard) from editText and set it on TextView using a button click and then have 3 buttons which changes the font of the textview. 
Hindi font is taken from the assets.

It is not working when I'm using hindi keyboard but it is working when I'm typing text using english keyboard.

Here is the code:

```
EditText et;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
}

public void setclick(View v){
    tv.setText(et.getText());
}

public void click1(View v){
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "hindi2.ttf"));
}

public void click2(View v){
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "hindi3.ttf"));
}

public void click3(View v){
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "hindi4.ttf"));
}
```

So my question is how can I change the font of hindi text which is acquired by user input.